# figure.canvas.flush_events of matplotlib is shutting down pygame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a made a small 3 link robotic arm in pygame that can track it's goal. In the same program I am trying get the joint positions, velocities and accelerations and plotting those values using matplotlib library in python.But whenever I call the figure.canvas.flush_events function of matplotlib, the pygame is shutting down and I am getting an error as Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped). Can anyone please help me in solving this?

I have attached below the error and sample code.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyK0h.png)

`plt.ion()

```
figure, ax = plt.subplots(3,figsize=(8,6))
plt.title("Dynamic Plot of Visualization",fontsize=25)

line1, = ax[0].plot(y,v1,label = 'theta_1_vel')
line2, = ax[0].plot(y,v2,label = 'theta_2_vel')

line3, = ax[1].plot(y,a1, label = 'theta_1_acc')
line4, = ax[1].plot(y,a2, label = 'theta_2_acc')

line5, = ax[2].plot(y,p1, label = 'theta_1_pos')
line6, = ax[2].plot(y,p2, label = 'theta_2_pos')

ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
ax[2].legend()


while True:
    line1.set_xdata(y)
    line2.set_xdata(y)
    line1.set_ydata(v1)
    line2.set_ydata(v2)

    line3.set_xdata(y)
    line4.set_xdata(y)
    line3.set_ydata(a1)
    line4.set_ydata(a2)

    line5.set_xdata(y)
    line6.set_xdata(y)
    line5.set_ydata(p1)
    line6.set_ydata(p2)
    
    figure.canvas.draw_idle()
    figure.canvas.flush_events()

    time.sleep(2)`
```